# Customizing CMFCRibbonBar im MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to customize the default MFC RibbonBar. I need to reduce its height, change its color etc, but so far i haven't found anything on how to do so. I've been to msdn, and they just tell you how to add new controls on the ribbon.Can any one please point me in the right direction? Is this ribbon control even customize-able? i mean apart from adding categories and other controls on it, i want to change the look of the ribbon.

Some code samples about how to work with MFCRibbonControl would be of great help too.

Comment: I don't think ribbon controls generally *are* customizable in the way you describe.

Comment: thats what i thought too. I just wanted to be sure of it before giving up on it.I think it needs to be edited in its XML file, the ribbon.-mfcribbon.ms file, but i cant find out where i can find a list of the properties listed here. Im sorry, but im new to mfc and its ribbon control, and right now im just trying to get it to work through hit and trial..

Comment: The only customization I've been able to do is to set the style (blue, high-contrast, black, etc...) as available when you create a new mfc project from the wizard and enable the style selection.

Comment: Thanks mmodahl. Can you tell me if you have modified the XML resource file? I cant seem to find the list of properties they set in xml for the ribbon bar.

Comment: You can derive a theme form the theme classes and then customize it in your own way. I did ti myself